# Get user like for each post

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a feature that lets users "like" a post (similar to Facebook). When I retrieve a post (or multiple posts), I need to include data in that query about whether or not the user liked that post.

In my `Post.php` model, I have the following relationship:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
}
```

Now, obviously, if I do the following query, it will retrieve *all* likes from *all* users, and not just the user logged in:

```
$posts = Post::with('likes')
    ->get();
```

So my question is, how can I create a relationship (maybe called `userLike()`) that would first check if the user is logged in, and then retrieve the like record for each post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `likes` tables has `user_id`. In this case, you can use [eager loading constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) like this:

```
$posts = Post::with([['likes' => function ($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', auth()->id());
}])->get();
```

Alternatively, you could create a relationship with `where` clause:

```
public function userLikes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Like::class)->where('user_id', auth()->id());
}
```

And then use it:

```
Post::with('userLikes')->get();
```

Comment: This would return the result under the `likes` key. But what if I wanted to retrieve both the user's like as well as all of the post's likes? Is there a way to change the key from `likes` to `userLike`?